# php arrays + função

Tags: php

Boas,

Tenho uma duvida..

Eu estou a usar sistema de erros[] em array.
Eu criei uma funçao que simplesmente mostrame o design do erro + mensagem

```
 warning_alert('Caracteres do tituto superiores a 4.');

 function warning_alert($text) {
  echo "
  <div class='alert warning'>
  <span class='closebtn'>&times;</span>  
  <strong><i class='fas fa-exclamation-circle'></i></strong> $text
  </div>"; 
 }
```

Aqui é onde ele diz a mensagem de ERRO. Mas não está a funcionar...

```
 $errors[] = warning_alert('Caracteres do tituto superiores a 4.');
```

Esta e a mensagem de erros
:

```
 if(strlen($ads_title) < 4 && strlen($ads_title) > 35) {

  $errors[] = warning_alert('Caracteres do tituto superiores a 4.'); 

 }
```

O Array errors funciona desta forma.

```
          if(!empty($errors)) {  

              echo display_errors($errors);

          } else {

             if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_destination)) {}
```

Alguma ideia?

Comment: mostrar o erro aonde???? o que você está fazendo que não aparece o erro?

Comment: não...Esta maneira assim nao da... $errors[] = warning_alert('Caracteres do tituto superiores a 4.'); É como se nao ouve-se erros...

Comment: Entenda, eu expliquei direito ate... o array $Errors[] é onde mostra todos os erros de cada verificaçao... mas eu quero mostrar o erro assim como fiz, pois a WARNING_ALERT e uma funçao com "ECHO $mensamgem"

Comment: Ja editei, veja agora se entende!

Comment: primeiro, se não precisa armazenar em um array! segundo dentro de uma função deveria retornar com return e fora chamar `echo warning_alert("");` então o seu código não está funcionando porque existe erros conceituais !!!

Comment: Pode-me corrigir?... assim aprendo..

Comment: Mas.. mesmo assim eu preciso do $errors [] = , porque faz parte do sistema, e nao posso usar ECHO

Comment: porque? você precisa do `$erros[]`? isso não está na sua pergunta o motivo principal!, é uma pergunta confusa!

Comment: Ja editei, veja a mensagem de ERRO!

Comment: com o seu código só isso funciona (mesmo tendo problemas) `if(strlen($ads_title) < 4 && strlen($ads_title) > 35) {
  warning_alert('Caracteres do tituto superiores a 4.'); 
}`

Comment: Entenda... eu tenho de usar o $errors[] pois ele valida numa outra verificaçao. Não existe nehuma maneira de Usar o Array $errors + a funçao?????????????

Comment: Troque o echo por return na sua função. Não sei como é a função que exibe os dados, talvez precise mexer nela também.

Answer (score 0):

Olá!!

Tente usar o `return` ao invés do echo, pois você quer que ele armazene no array, porém a função está sem retorno.